# Merge big file parts faster in java

Tags: java, filesystems

I'm writing a java rest service to support parallel upload of parts of a large file. I am writing these parts in separate files and merging them using file channel. I have a sample implemented in Golang, it does the same but when it merges the parts, it takes no time. When I use file channel or read from one stream and write to the final file, it takes long time. The difference I think is, Golang has ability to keep the data on the disk as it is and just merge them by not actually moving the data. Is there any way I can do the same in java?
 Here is my code that merges parts, I loop through this method for all parts:

```
private void mergeFileUsingChannel(String destinationPath, String sourcePath, long partSize, long offset) throws Exception{
    FileChannel outputChannel = null;
    FileChannel inputChannel = null;
    try{
        outputChannel = new FileOutputStream(new File(destinationPath)).getChannel();
        outputChannel.position(offset);

        inputChannel = new FileInputStream(new File(sourcePath)).getChannel();
        inputChannel.transferTo(0, partSize, outputChannel);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        if(inputChannel != null)
            inputChannel.close();
        if(outputChannel != null){
            outputChannel.close();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Might the operating-system and file-system type be relevant to this question?

Comment: Server is fedora 24. I am not sure about file system. I am transferring files to HDD,SSD and network locations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation of [FileChannel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#transferTo-long-long-java.nio.channels.WritableByteChannel-) `transferTo` states:

> "Many operating systems can transfer bytes directly from the filesystem cache to the target channel without actually copying them."

So the code you have written is correct, and the inefficiency you are seeing is probably related to the underlying file-system type.

One small optimization I could suggest would be to open the file in [append](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#open-java.nio.file.Path-java.util.Set-java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...-) mode.

> "Whether the advancement of the position and the writing of the data are done in a single atomic operation is system-dependent"

Beyond that, you may have to think of a way to work around the problem. For example, by creating a large enough contiguous file as a first step.

---

**EDIT:** I also noticed that you are not explicitly closing your FileOutputStream. It would be best to hang on to that and close it, so that all the File Descriptors are closed.

Comment: So I tried few combinations and concluded that its OS and file system which  makes the I/O operations slow or fast. I tried NTFS and ext4 formatted HDD connected on USB port and got same results(1min 25 sec for merging 30 parts of 1GB file). And when I tried same on my windows machine on board HDD, it was less than 10 seconds. I am now reading upon file systems and how OS manages I/O. If anyone has a good link to read about, I would appreciate that. Also, I looked at the GoLang sample, it has a trick, it merges part of file to the final fine as the part arrives on server, not at the end.

Comment: Markling this as answered as I've used the same approach I've posted in question. The time in merge in dependent on the media itself. And java's NIO does a good job in merging using channel's transferto method to avoid context switches and buffer copy. I need to play with my settings considering client-server connection(LAN/WAN) and destination media type to get best out of what is available, Thanks!